# SharePoint 2013 - How to seperate urls and page headings

Tags: url, wiki-pages, url-rewriting

We just got updated to SharePoint 2013 platform and I have now for 2 days been fighting with what seems to be a typical Microsoft issue :(

When creating pages or **wiki pages** the url seems to be 100% linked to the page heading. This creates very ugly urls which is not very user friendly.

In older versions of sharepoint there were a way around this where I first gave the page a url name like 'this_is_my_new_page' and thereafter renamed the page to 'This is my new page'. In this way I kept nice urls and good headings.

However in 2013 if I change the page name the url dynamicly changes with it :( ... what a mess this will create if people update the wiki headings all links to that site is lost :(

I want to be able to set the url and page heading independently, is there a way to do this?

- url: how_to_use_this_library
- page heading: How To Use This Library`

Default url would be `How%20To%20Use%20This%20Library.aspx` which is NOT user friendly!

Answer (score 0):

When creating links between Wiki pages, you can use link format `[[MyNewPage|My New Page]]`, which will use the spaced string as the title.

I understand this is only 10% answer to your question, but better that than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However this only affect the text in the links. When opening the page in the link the page heading will still be equal to the url: MyNewPage

Comment: Decreased percentage to 10%.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use javascript to change the site page title if needed.
Insert a script editor webpart to the page and use the following script:

```
<script> document.getElementById("DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").innerHTML="New Site Title"; </script>
```

"New Site Title" is where you insert your new page Title

Reference is found [here](http://www.balestra.be/2013/09/change-the-title-of-a-sharepoint-2013-site-with-javascript-or-jquery.html)